# Export current DSC configuration for import to another server (using IIS website as an example)

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, dsc

I'm trying to wrap my hand around DSC in PowerShell 4.0, what's possible, and what's not.   I've installed [xWebAdministration Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be).

Could I create a website in IIS, then somehow export it to the a .ps1 file (I think in the MOF format).  For example, txWebAdministration has a sample called xWebAdministration\Examples\Sample_xWebsite_NewWebsite.ps1.  Could I use an existing website to build a file like this?  Or do I have to type everything in manually?

I'm basically trying to jump in and try some things without reading from end-to-end.  I was hoping Get-DscConfiguration would somehow read my IIS configuration and create such a file.

For example, in SQLServer, you can create a database and tables using the graphical user interface of SQL Studio Management Studio (SSMS), then export a script to re-create those same tables on another server.

Is such a concept possible with DSC, or am I missing the boat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this at the moment.

Keep in mind DSC is very new and quite sparse. The DSC Resource Kit is created by people at Microsoft, but isn't supported or all that official.

You could write a script to parse an existing web site and export it to a configuration in a PS1, or even directly into an MOF (it's a text file too), but there is nothing close to this functionality existing at the moment.

Your best bet is probably to type it out manually at this time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that creates a DSC configuration from an existing machine called [GuardRail](http://www.scriptrock.com/blog/powershell-dsc-with-guardrail) but I think it will not support the experimental xWebAdministration Module. As briantist said,  it wouldn't be too difficult to create a powershell script that uses WebAdministration commandlets to produce a DSC configuration.

In fact a workmate asked me the same question today and I'm considering writing one. If you I'll update my answer in a few days with a script that will do this.